# As a journalist, how do I learn about impending legislation or executive orders?

Tags: journalism

How do news companies find out that the government plans to pass a law in a couple of years, or that the president is about to sign an executive order?

Do they contact the government workers and ask to be notified of any news that the government has? If so what are the requirements to be signed up -- is this something I can do? If there is a different method used, what is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to writing in any way.

Comment: It has to do with journalism which is what a lot of the questions on this site are about

Comment: I've edited to clarify your focus on journalistic procedure, and voted to reopen. And hey, welcome to the site! :D

Comment: The bills are (usually) made public before legislature is set to vote. Executive orders and rushed/secretive bills typically become known only after the signing or voting. For those, journalists cultivate their "sources" in legislature and administration. Note that information "leaks" through those sources can potentially get not only the source, but the journalist himself in trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incumbent White House Press Secretary (a senior White House official whose primary responsibility is to act as spokesperson for the *executive* branch of the United States government administration) is Sarah Huckabee Sanders. She is the single designated staff person or office responsible for managing the relationship between the president and journalists / media entities.

One of her roles is to field questions from the White House press corps, which is a group of journalists, correspondents, or members of the media usually stationed at the White House in Washington, D.C., to cover the President of the United States, White House events, and news briefings. A partial list (I can't vouch for the accuracy of this) may be obtained from the [White House Press Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_press_corps) page on Wikipedia.

This information suggests several routes to make your way towards the information you require:

- Receive updates from White House via this Newsletter: [Get Involved](https://www.whitehouse.gov/get-involved/)
- Contact individual members of the [White House Press Corp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_press_corps)
- Cultivate your own contacts in and around the White House.

I would suggest that the only way that a journalist is going to get the news you refer to in advance is to build up a network of contacts in and around the people responsible for these decisions. There doesn't seem to be a shortcut to this.

Good luck going forward.